# How to autoload helper functions as needed in Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Say you have 1 file per function:

/src/Helpers/fooHelper.php

```
<?php

namespace MyHelper;

function fooHelper() {};
```

/src/Helpers/barHelper.php

```
<?php

namespace MyHelper;

function barHelper() {};
```

I see that there is

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["src/Helpers/functions.php"]
}
```

Is it possible to autoload these functions via Composer on demand instead of every request?

Comment: if you need them on demand, then just load the helper class when you need it with laravel (not with composer)

Comment: @Valentino This is not Laravel

Comment: my bad, I see that whatever it is it uses namespaces (as Laravel does). I expect you can load a class on demand with some syntax like "use App\Helpers\MyClass;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to autoload these functions via Composer on demand instead of every request?

No, there is no autoloading support for functions in PHP. You need to either load them manually or add files with functions declaration to `autoload.files` config in `composer.json` - they're will be loaded on each request, even if you never use it.

The only sane workaround at this moment is to wrap helpers in some static class, which could be autoloaded without any trouble.

```
class MyHelper {

    public static function fooHelper() {}

    public static function barHelper() {}
}

MyHelper::fooHelper();
MyHelper::barHelper();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add it for every helper file you should do the following way:

```
"autoload": {
    "files" : [
        "path_to file_1.php",
        "path_to file_2.php",
        "and so on"
    ]
}
```

It should work after running the command: `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: AFIK that will autoload everything at once.

Comment: But you should run `composer update` after each edit of composer.json file.

Comment: Still, it will load everything at once. I need to load the functions on demand / only when they are actually used.